# How to copyright unpublished work during Phd

Tags: phd, copyright, interview

How do I protect my unpublished phd work (which i am planning on publishing soon)?
I am conducting expert interviews and I will have to send parts of my work to them for validation. But, how to ensure that they don't copy it or use it in their work before I publish it?

Comment: In many countries, creative work is protected by copyright by default, so there is nothing you need to do. But, copyright doesn't prevent others from copying/using it.

Comment: It is possible that work done during your PhD studies belongs to the University. Check your school's policies on copyright.

Comment: What kind of work it is?It is related to programming, data analysis, or mathematical?

Comment: @Ric: *It is possible that work done during your PhD studies belongs to the University. Check your school's policies on copyright.* What country are you talking about? In the US, your statement is not accurate, because the university's policy has no legal effect on whether or not something is a work for hire. See http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68873/copyright-for-lectures-slides-and-textbook-university-or-professor

Comment: @BenCrowell: But in many cases, even if the work is a "work for hire", the university's policy states that the faculty/student author gets to retain the copyright anyway.  Essentially, the law gives the copyright to the university, but the university's policy gives it right back to the author. So the policy is relevant.

Comment: @NateEldredge: *Essentially, the law gives the copyright to the university, but the university's policy gives it right back to the author.* Note true. The law says that this type of work is typically *not* work for hire. See http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68873/copyright-for-lectures-slides-and-textbook-university-or-professor . Therefore university policy is typically *not* relevant.

Comment: Well, @BenCrowell , if the PhD student was hired to work in a research group or was funded with a certain grant, than the research output could be the property of the research group or granting body. Such PhD students sign IP agreements after they a hired.

Answer (score 7):

In most countries your work is copyrighted when you create it. That is simple. The other question you need to address yourself is, why would folks you have contacted steal your work? This is a fear many people have, but almost never actually happens. Get over that fear.